# echoing a image in view page from DB

Tags: image, codeigniter

i'm using Ci and i have a form that saves image in a folder. The name of the image is saved in my DB. I want to echo this image.i can retrieve the image name from Db but when i'm echoing this the image it is not showing. I think my controller and model is working fine but there is something wrong with my view.

the part where i'm echoing the image:

```
           <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/$info[0]->image"></img>
```

info is the array where the information from the DB(like image name) is saved.
I cannot find my mistake.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're using $info[0]->image outside the PHP tags.
It should be like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$info[0]->image; ?>" />
```

One more mistake is how you write the HTML tag IMG